# Treat second column with spaces as one column with awk

Tags: shell, awk

For a file that looks like this:

```
Paul    white male 34 
Jane    black female 22
Sam     white male 44
```

I would like an awk line to treat everything after the first column on the same line as a second column, so that I could run it on the above and produce the following

```
white male 34 
black female 22
white male 44
```

Currently, awk '{print $2} would only output the first word, not the rest of the line.

THanks!

Comment: Is that a tab or a chain of blank chars between Paul and white?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of these should work for you depending what that first space character is and the rest of your spaces are:

```
awk '{sub(/[^ ]+[ ]+/,"")}1' file
awk -F'\t' '{print $2}' file
```

Comment: +1, I think first one is better. If OP don't mind an extra space at the beginning then: `awk '{$1="";print}' file` would work as well.

Comment: Assigning $1 would mess around with other spaces on the line which might not be desirable.

Answer (score 0):

Ed Morton provided a standard way and work for your needs.

I would mention another (tricky) way:

In your awk line, instead of printing `$2`, you could set `$1=""` then print the whole line.

```
awk '!($1="")' file
```

see the test:

```
kent$  echo "Paul    white male 34 
Jane    black female 22
Sam     white male 44"|awk '!($1="")'
 white male 34
 black female 22
 white male 44
```

this one-liner is very short and give you the output. however there is a leading blank on each line. It is also easy to be removed by:

```
awk '!($1="")&&gsub(/^ /,"")'
```